# Interacting with Local webpage through Application in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, html, ajax

I want to interact with my local HTML page through my C++ application. Just like using java script console, we can edit a page in real time, e.g

```
document.getElementById('divlayer').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Similarly i want to call such functions in real time through my application.
Can you give me some idea if there is a way to accomplish this job?
I am using Google Chrome at the moment.

Do i need some plugin, but how can i make plugin to interact with my application then?
Also, i head about JQuery, can this be done using JQuery? Or do i have to try some server mecahnism may be using Ajax??

Comment: Question is a bit of a mess. What's a "local" HTML page? You can have local HTML _files_, which are files in the local filesystem. You can obviously edit files. You can also have HTML pages in a webbrowser. There's no meaningful "local" attribute for that. In short, the probelm domain isn't clear. What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: By Local i mean it is not served by a web-server. Rather you open a local HTML file in web-browser and then you can change it in real time without refreshing or reloading a new page by modifying the DOM. Actually if you read again my question makes sense. You just have to be in the mood to understand what i want to say

Comment: That really doesn't matter. By the time the HTML file has been read, it's become a DOM (Document Object Model) in the browser and the origin no longer matters. However, it now matters in which browser the DOM exists. Javascript can manipulate the DOM because it's loaded in precisely the same browser, even in the same tab (for tabbed webbroswers).

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can control your IE browser with COM on Windows, and you can interact with the page with it. But I didn't try it with C++, I just use it with Python and it works well. May be you'd like to check it out.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there any documentation available or can you refer me to any example.